# Include hour in timer countdown

Tags: c#, wpf, timespan, dispatchertimer

I am trying to create a countdown that includes hours.

```
private int time = 3660;        

public MainWindow()
{
    var vm = new TimerViewModel();

    InitializeComponent();

    // get display setting - 2 means extended
    int displayType = Screen.AllScreens.Length;

    // set the windows datacontext
    DataContext = vm;

    // set up the timedispatcher
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dt.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}   

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(time)
    {
        case int x when x > 10 && x <= 20:                 
            TimerPreview.Foreground = Brushes.Orange;

            time--;
            break;

        .....................

        default:
            TimerPreview.Foreground = Brushes.LimeGreen;
            time--;
            break;
    }

    TimerPreview.Content = string.Format("00:{0:00}:{1:00}",  time / 60, time % 60);
}
```

I cannot work out how to get the countdown working correctly with hours. It works great with minutes and seconds.

```
TimerPreview.Content = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", time ???, time ??? 60, time % 60);
```

I have tried a number of combinations but have failed to find a solution. What am I missing? Many thanks.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of code that you are not posting on here, i barely understand what you are trying to do, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can help you better

Comment: Fair comment, sorry, I just didn't want to post too much clutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `3600` (the number of seconds in an hour), and use the modulus operator on the minutes just like you're doing on the seconds (since you want 60 minutes to appear to roll over into a new hour):

```
TimerPreview.Content =
    string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", time / 3600, (time / 60) % 60, time % 60);

//  320 -> 00:05:20
// 7199 -> 01:59:59
// 7201 -> 02:00:01
```

Comment: That's great thank you so much. I didn't divide time by 60 for the minutes. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another (arguably more readable) option would be to use a `TimeSpan` to handle the formatting:

```
TimerPreview.Content = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Result when `time` is `3660`:

> `01:01:00`

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to @GrantWinney for pointing out that the default string format for a `TimeSpan` is the same as above, unless the timespan is greater than a day, in which case it includes days as well. So you could just do:

```
TimerPreview.Content = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time).ToString();
```

Comment: Wow, you're right! I assumed the default would include days as well (`@"d\.hh\:mm\:ss"`);

Comment: Ahhh.. just tested it and it does include `Days` by default if there are 1 or more days represented by the `TimeSpan`

Comment: This works a treat too, thank you. I will not be doing days and the user will not be able to pass more than a couple of hours.